# Represent a pure state in terms of 2 antipodal points on the Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, bloch-sphere

I recently had an assignment where the question is based on the assumption that we can write any pure state qubit $|\phi \rangle$ as:
        $$|\phi \rangle = \gamma |\psi\rangle + \delta |\psi^\perp \rangle$$
Where $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\psi^\perp \rangle$ are 2 antipodal points on the Bloch sphere:
$$ |\psi\rangle =  \cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle +e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} |1\rangle$$
$$ |\psi^\perp\rangle =  \cos \frac{\theta + \pi}{2} |0\rangle +e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2} |1\rangle$$

I have a lingering question about how this actually works. So far I got:
$$|\phi\rangle= \gamma |\psi\rangle + \delta |\psi^{\perp}\rangle$$
$$= \gamma \left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle +e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} |1\rangle \right) + \delta  \left(\cos \frac{\theta + \pi}{2} |0\rangle +e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2} |1\rangle \right)$$
$$ = \left(\gamma \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + \delta \cos \frac{\theta + \pi}{2}\right)|0\rangle
  + \left(\gamma e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} + \delta e^{i\varphi} \sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2}\right)|1\rangle$$
$$\Rightarrow \alpha =  \gamma \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + \delta \cos \frac{\theta + \pi}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \beta = \gamma e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} + \delta e^{i\varphi} \sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2}$$
So $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$. I'm not sure if I can solve this equation. I wonder if it's solvable or is there a better way to go about understanding writing a pure state in $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\psi^\perp \rangle$ basis. I know that they are orthonormal so intuitively it should work.

Comment: I think $\varphi$ in the $|\psi^\perp\rangle$ definition should be with "$-$" sign, am I right? The main question/problem is about how to prove $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$? Or is it about finding $\gamma$ and $\delta$ for given $\alpha$ and $ \beta$?

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan hm why should it be $-\varphi$? I thought it's only negative when you take the complex conjugate i.e. $\langle \psi^\perp|$. And yes, the question is to prove that. I could have been clearer about it.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan I guess once I prove $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$ then it's should be easy to find $\gamma$ and $\delta$.

Comment: But antipodal points don't have the same $\varphi$ in the Bloch sphere (here I am thinking just geometrically).

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\langle \psi^\perp| = \cos \frac{\theta + \pi}{2} \langle 0|  -e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2} \langle 1|$? Then when you take $\langle\psi^\perp | \psi\rangle = 0$

Comment: ok, sorry, you are right :). But one more thing. How I remember $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ in definition of Bloch sphere. So, shouldn't we have $\frac{\pi - \theta}{2}$ in the arguments of $sin$ and $cos$ and $\varphi + \pi$  in the phase of $|\psi^\perp \rangle$.

Comment: Hm you're right. I've seen both notations being used and I'm not sure if they're equivalent. Given the angle constraint, it'd make more sense to use yours. I wonder if without the constraint, would they be equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent in some sense (they differ by a global phase). I just noticed that my prove also will work for the definitions used in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106406/discussion-between-davit-khachatryan-and-cat-mai).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two antipodal states in the Bloch sphere (note that $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$):

\begin{equation}
|\psi \rangle = \cos \frac{\theta}{2}  |0 \rangle + e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2}  |1 \rangle
\\
|\psi^\perp \rangle = \cos \frac{\pi - \theta}{2}  |0 \rangle + e^{i\varphi + \pi}\sin \frac{\pi - \theta}{2}  |1 \rangle = \sin \frac{\theta}{2}  |0 \rangle - e^{i\varphi}\cos \frac{\theta}{2}  |1 \rangle
\end{equation}

The expression for $|\psi^\perp \rangle$ from the question is different from this $|\psi^\perp \rangle$ by a global phase. The reason why I prefer this notation is that I want to keep Bloch sphere formalism (e.g. $0 \leq (\pi - \theta) \leq \pi$ constrant that is true for $|\psi^\perp \rangle$ presented here). Note that:

$$\langle \psi | \psi^\perp \rangle = \cos \frac{\theta}{2}  \sin \frac{\theta}{2} - \sin \frac{\theta}{2}  \cos \frac{\theta}{2}  = 0$$

By doing the same calculations we can obtain for $|\phi\rangle= \gamma |\psi\rangle + \delta |\psi^{\perp}\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$:

\begin{align*}
&\alpha =  \gamma \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + \delta \sin \frac{\theta}{2}
\\
&\beta = \gamma e^{i\varphi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} - \delta e^{i\varphi} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{align*}

Then (here I take into account that $|e^{i\varphi}| = 1$):

\begin{equation}
|\alpha|^2 = |\gamma|^2 \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} + |\delta|^2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}
+ 2 Re(\gamma)  Re(\delta) \cos \frac{\theta}{2}\sin \frac{\theta}{2}  + 
 2 Im(\gamma)  Im(\delta) \cos \frac{\theta}{2}\sin \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|\beta|^2 = |\gamma|^2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} + |\delta|^2 \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} - 2Re(\gamma) Re(\delta)\cos \frac{\theta}{2} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} - 2Im(\gamma) Im(\delta)\cos \frac{\theta}{2} \sin \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{equation}

Because if we have two complex numbers $z_1 = x_1 + i y_1$ and $z_2 = x_2 + i y_2$, then:

$$|z_1 \pm z_2|^2 = (x_1 \pm x_2)^2 + (y_1 \pm y_2)^2 = |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 \pm 2 x_1 x_2 \pm 2 y_1 y_2$$

After summing the expressions for $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ we will obtain:

$$|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = \left(|\gamma|^2 + |\delta|^2 \right) \left(\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} \right) =1$$

Comment: I don't really follow the calculation. Why is there 2 terms of $Im$? I think the first $Re$ term is from $|\alpha^2|$ and the other one is from $|\beta^2|$. But I don't get where the 2 $Im$ terms come from. Also, for 2 complex number, did you do the calculation directly instead of expanding $e^{i\varphi} = \cos\varphi + i\sin\varphi$?

Comment: @CatMai $2 Re(\gamma)Re(\delta)... + 2Im(\gamma)Im(\delta)...$ is coming from $|\alpha|^2$. $ - 2 Re(\gamma)Re(\delta)... - 2Im(\gamma)Im(\delta)...$ is coming from $|\beta|^2$.

Comment: For example, for $\alpha$: $z_1 = \gamma \cos(\theta/2)$, $z_2 = \delta \sin(\theta/2)$ , $x_1 = Re(\gamma cos(\theta/2))$, $x_2 = Re(\delta \sin(\theta/2)$ , $y_1 = Im(\gamma cos(\theta/2))$ and $y_2 = Im(\delta \sin(\theta/2)$.

Comment: For $|\beta|^2 = |e^{i\varphi}|^2|\gamma \sin(\theta/2)- \delta \cos(\theta/2)|^2 $ and $|e^{i\varphi}|^2 = 1$. So we shouldn't worry about $\varphi$.

Comment: @CatMai I edited my answer in order to show the calculations of $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ separately.